# Mysql: Get all records which are insert before certain hour

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I need a query from which I get rows from a table which are insert before a certain hours.

Let say 1 hour. I need all records from the table which insert before 1 hour.

I have "createdon" column in table.

For example, I have a table foo, columns are as follows:

- ID
- Name
- Created_on (with timestamp set as default)

There is some records, as follows:

First Record
 - 1
 - A
 - 2013-07-19 04:12:00

Second Record
 - 2
 - B
 - 2013-07-19 02:00:00

If current time is 5:00 pm, then query should return second record only. not first record because it is created with in a hour.

Comment: . . You really ned to better explain what you are looking for.  Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct query for this is as follows:

select *
from table_name 
where created_on < date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour);

Thank You all for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for SQL

```
select  * from TableName where DateColumn > (DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())-1)
```

You can replace `1` to any value you want.

Comment: But there is no function with name DATEPART in mysql

Comment: @Sachin agree with Abhinav

Comment: @Abhinav you can use `hour` function in mySql. Described here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm#function_hour